# Can we get higher internet speeds even with low BW message signals?

Tags: communication, wireless, digital-communications, bandwidth, digital-audio

Consider a case where i’m listening to a recorded audio on internet.Basically the useful audio Frequency range lies b/w 40hz to 4khz, which has a BW of 4khz which is pretty low ,does that mean the audio has low data rate? But it loads up pretty quickly.

Another question:-  does higher message signal BW mean  it can accomadate MORE info at a time and lead to fater data rates, as more data is being transferred per second?

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are searching for is called *channel capacity*.  If you do a web search on that term you should find a lot of information.

Basically, the capacity of a channel is determined by it's bandwidth, noise level, and the power you can put into your signal.  Theoretically, if I could only send one symbol per second I could still achieve 1Mbps as long as the noise was low enough to distinguish gradiations in the signal of \$10^{-6}\$.  OTOH, a 1MHz wide channel with so much noise that I could only send binary signals could also achieve that speed.

The "truth" is always somewhere in the middle, and provides a continual challenge for communications engineers to get more speed for less money on existing channels.

Answer (score 0):

The data throughput for a channel is defined by two things:

- Signal bandwidth
- Signal-to-noise ratio

This is expressed in the Shannon Information Theorem. That is:

$$C = W *log_2(1 + SNR)$$
Where W represents the bandwidth and C is the capacity of the channel.

Mind, this is the *information* capacity for data that has *infinite entropy*, that is, the data is truly random and thus isn't compressible by any means.

More about the Shannon Information Theorem here: http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS01/19548-U/shannon.html

And, C. E. Shannon's actual paper: http://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf

If we employ compression, the throughput can be increased substantially. This can range from about 2:1 for a simple scheme like G.711 mu-law to much higher using transform+entropy based codecs like MP3 and others.

A comparison of compression formats here: http://www.sericyb.com.au/audio.html